# Как убрать lazy load на странице для первых двух элементах?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

а остальных оставить

можно как-то без изменения разметки? существенной

иначе такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.product__wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product__pic {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__wrap">
  <a href="#" class="product__pic">
    <picture class="product__image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x">
    </picture>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="product__pic">
    <picture class="product__image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x">
    </picture>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="product__pic">
    <picture class="product__image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x">
    </picture>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="product__pic">
    <picture class="product__image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x">
    </picture>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="product__pic">
    <picture class="product__image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-src="https://i.ibb.co/RjNX704/product2-1x.png" data-srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" srcset="https://i.ibb.co/t8rbLCV/product2-2x.png 2x">
    </picture>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам класс`class=" lazyloaded"`  из img  убрать? Через JS комманду `removeClass`
Выбор первых 2-х `.product__image:first-child, .product__image:nth-child(2)` JS позволяет.

Comment: зачем js ? у автора указано "без изменения разметку существенной", это изменение будет не существенно.

Comment: @teran Что за "разметку СУЩЕСТВЕННОЙ"? 
Ваш вариант ?

Comment: *разметки. Мой вариант - отредактировать разметку убрав класс в нужных местах руками. это несущественное изменение, что удовлетворяет запросу автора. js тут не нужен.